# How to use min function in creating DataFrame calculated columns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
x=[[2,3],[1,8],[5,6]]
df_a=pd.DataFrame(x,columns=['a','b'])
df_a["Diff"]=min(df_a['a'],0)-min(df_a['b'],0)
```

I am trying to create a calculated column based on min function, but getting error as

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

My ultimate aim is to create a column that tells Day over Day increase/decrease of debit values (aka negative values).

Please Help

Comment: Why are you adding a zero at then end of the min function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `min` is the Python's `min` function, I don't think it takes a Pandas series. You can use Pandas' `clip`:

```
df_a['Diff'] = df_a['a'].clip(upper=0) - df_a['b'].clip(upper=0)
```